# $lte not working as expected even after number String converted to Int in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Since $lte and $gt does a lexicographical comparison if the value is in string format, I have tried to convert the values to int or double. But I am not getting the expected results. For this case i want the query to execute to 2 as only 2 documents are present with the "userDL" field value less than or equal to 5. Please note: I cannot use aggregate and I have to use db.collection.find(query).count(). Please help me here with the query.

**Collection content:**

```
{ "_id" : "14_0", "data" : [ { "dn" : "subdata=data_a", "userUL" : "0", "objectClass" : "NEWDATA", "userDL" : "5" } ] }

{ "_id" : "15_0", "data" : [ { "dn" : "subdata=data_b", "userUL" : "0", "objectClass" : "NEWDATA", "userDL" : "3" } ] }

{ "_id" : "16_0", "data" : [ { "dn" : "subdata=data_c", "userUL" : "0", "objectClass" : "NEWDATA", "userDL" : "9" } ] }
```

1st, I tried normal querying which gave me unsupported conversion error:

```
db.testcol.find({ $expr: { $lte: [ { $toDouble: "$data.userDL" }, 5 ] } }).count()

2020-09-18T06:26:37.010+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: count failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unsupported conversion from array to double in $convert with no onError value",
        "code" : 241,
        "codeName" : "ConversionFailure"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:376:11
@(shell):1:1
```

The above error i fixed in the below query but i am using aggregate. This works fine in terms of comparison and outputs true/false.

```
db.testcol.aggregate([{ $project:{ adjustedGrades:{$map:{input: "$data.userDL",as: "grade",in: {$lte : [{ $toInt: "$$grade" },5] } }}}}])

{ "_id" : "14_0", "adjustedGrades" : [ true ] }
{ "_id" : "15_0", "adjustedGrades" : [ true ] }
{ "_id" : "16_0", "adjustedGrades" : [ false ] }
```

I tried using the above aggregate inside find query but either i am not getting any output or the wrong output(i am getting 3 instead to 2)

```
db.testcol.find({ $expr: { $lte: [ {$map:{input: "$data.userDL",as: "grade",in: { $toInt: "$$grade" } }}  , 5 ] } })

no output here

db.testcol.find({$expr: {$map: {input: "$data.userDL",as: "grade",in: {$lte : [{ $toInt: "$$grade" },5] } }}}).count()

3
```

***[UPDATE]***

```
> db.testcol.aggregate([{ $project:{ adjustedGrades:{$map:{input: "$data.userDL",as: "grade",in: {$lte : [{ $toInt: "$$grade" },5] } }}}}, {$match: {adjustedGrades: {$eq: true}}}])

{ "_id" : "14_0", "adjustedGrades" : [ true ] }
{ "_id" : "15_0", "adjustedGrades" : [ true ] }
```

I want to able able to do this using db.collection.find(). Can someone help here? I don't actually need the adjustedGrades field. I want these 2 documents to be returned when I do db.testcol.find(aggregatequery). Finally I want to be able to do db.testcol.find(aggregatequery).count().
PS: I have to use find() and count() only.

Comment: `$map` returns an array, which is truthy, try using $reduce to return a boolean.

Comment: Hi, could you help me with some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of using `$reduce` to iterate the array and test each element:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$data",
      initialValue: false,
      in: {
        $or: [
          "$$value",
          {$lte: [{$toDouble: "$$this.userDL"}, 5]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w13swTMqiyg)

Note that using `$expr` in this way will not be able to use an index.

If it is permissible to modify the documents, updating so that each `userDL` is numeric will permit both querying directly and indexing that field.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. This would work just fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.insert({a:'20',b:[{c:'20'}]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.find({$expr:{$gte:[{$convert:{input:'$a',to:'int'}},30]}})
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.find({$expr:{$gte:[{$convert:{input:'$a',to:'int'}},3]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f64632b24059b0e3ee998b8"), "a" : "20", "b" : [ { "c" : "20" } ] }
```

Comment: When i checked if value greater than 30 also, I am getting the same output. The result should be 0 here. **> db.foo.find({$expr:{$gte:['$b.c',30]}})**        _{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6475a7c6bb04ea73d5e416"), "a" : "20", "b" : [ { "c" : "20" } ] }_

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reponse but the updated answer doesn't work on the array elements. I did this **> db.foo.find({$expr:{$gte:['$b.c',30]}})** and got the above conversion error in the question that i posted above.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> db.getCollection("myCollection").find({ "data.0.userDL": { $lte: "5" } }, {}).count()

---